# async-each-series with index/key

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am using "async-each-series" npm in node js to iterate the Array.
But I am not able to find array current key.
Below is the sample code.

```
var each = require('async-each-series');
each(['foo','bar','baz'], function(el, next) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(el);
    next();
  }, Math.random() * 5000);
}, function (err) {
  console.log('finished');
});
```

In the above code if I add 3rd parameter it gives 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

`async-each-series` is old and I suggest change it to something modern. Like this http://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html .

If you want index just use http://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#eachOf

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fixed links. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to add index field in the object itself and the use async.eachSeries as you want.

```js
var someArray=[{'name':'john','rank':'24'},{'name':'johny','rank':'244'}];

for(i=0; i<someArray.length; i++){
   someArray[i]['index'] = i;
}

console.log(someArray);
```